# getchar does not stop when using scanf

Tags: c, getchar

I have a difficulty understanding `getchar()`. In the following program `getchar` works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("Type Enter to continue...");
    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```

However, in the following program, `getchar` does not create a delay and the program ends:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char command[100];
    scanf("%s", command );
    printf("Type Enter to continue...");
    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```

I have the following weired workaround, which works, but I don't understand why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char command[100];
    int i;
    scanf("%s", command );
    printf("Type Enter to continue...");
    while ( getchar() != '\n') {
      i=0; 
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;    
}
```

So my questions are:
  1. What is `scanf` doing?  Why does `scanf` do this ?
  2. Why is my work around working?
  3. What is a good way to emulate the following Python code:

```
raw_input("Type Enter to continue")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The input is only sent to the program after you typed a newline, but

```
scanf("%s", command );
```

leaves the newline in the input buffer, since the `%s`<sup>(1)</sup> format stops when the first whitespace character is encountered after some non-whitespace, `getchar()` then returns that newline immediately and doesn't need to wait for further input.

Your workaround works because it clears the newline from the input buffer before calling `getchar()` once more.

To emulate the behaviour, clear the input buffer before printing the message,

```
scanf("%s", command);
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
if (c == EOF) {
    // input stream ended, do something about it, exit perhaps
} else {
    printf("Type Enter to continue\n");
    getchar();
}
```

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that using `%s` in `scanf` is very unsafe, you should restrict the input to what your buffer can hold with a field-width, `scanf("%99s", command)` will read at most 99 (`sizeof(command) - 1)`) characters into `command`, leaving space for the 0-terminator.

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace is a delimiter for 5y3 %s format specifier, and *newline* is regarded as whitespace, so it remains buffered. Console input is normally line oriented, so a subsequent call to getchar() will return immediately because a 'line' remains buffered.

```
scanf("%s", command );
while( getchar() != '\n' ){ /* flush to end of input line */ }
```

Equally if you use getchar() or %c to get a single character you normally need to flush the line, but in this case the character entered may itself be a *newline* so you need a slightly different solution:

```
scanf("%c", ch );
while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ){ /* flush to end of input line */ }
```

similarly for getchar():

```
ch = getchar();
while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ){ /* flush to end of input line */ }
```

The sensible thing to do of course is to wrap these solutions into stand-alone specialised input functions that you can reuse and also use as a place to put common input validation and error checking code (as in Daniel Fischer's answer which sensibly checks for EOF - you would normally want to avoid having to duplicate those checks and error handling everywhere).

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather first use `fgets` and then use `sscanf` to parse the input. I have been doing this stuff like this for a long time and the behaviour has been more predictable than using plain `scanf`.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I have something easier: add another `getchar()` ... problem solved!!

Comment: that doesn't necessarily solve the problem, you still may have more than one byte in the buffer and `getchar()` will then return immediately.

Answer (score -4):

after taking command input flush the stdin.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

but flushing a input stream results in undefined behavior (though Microsoft's C library defines the behaviour as an extension).

Comment: fflush() is undefined for input streams.

Comment: -1: applying `fflush()` to an input stream (or an input/output stream for which the last operation was input) is one of the few specific examples of Undefined Behavior specified by the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: Note that while this works with Microsoft's C library, it certainly does not with the GNU C library. Avoid.

Comment: I have mentioned about the undefined behavior.

Comment: @DebobrotoDas: you *ninja-edited* your answer and the downvotes (at least mine) couldn't be revoked. I'll edit your answer and revoke my downvote in a second.

Comment: It was I who downvoted your answer. I did that before the answer had the information about Undefined Behavior. When I noticed you had changed it I couldn't revoke the downvote, but revoked it right after I edited your answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It remains bad advice IMO - "undefined" includes not actually doing anything at all.  It may or may not deserve a down vote, but certainly not an up vote.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined and not a good habit. I recomend to first use `fgets` and then `sscanf`. It's much safer and predictable.