# Problems with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char C, B;
    int x;



    printf("What comes after G\n");
    scanf("%c", &C);

    printf("What comes after O\n");
    scanf("%c", &B);

    printf("What is your age?\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("You said %c comes after G, %c after T and you're %d years old? Right?", C, B, x);

    return 0;
}
```

The **problem** is whenever you run the code it skips the second question "What comes after O" and then asks "What is your age?"

The only way I could **avoid the program skip the 2nd question** was by adding a space to the code

```
printf("What comes after O\n");
    scanf(" %c", &B);
```

You can see the **space** between **"** and **%c**

Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: Had the same problem> see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653884/getchar-does-not-stop-when-using-scanf

Answer (score 3):

You need to eat up the white space (i.e. new line) - as per the manual page http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf` to eat the single character without assigning it to anything like this::

```
scanf( "%[^\n]%*c", &C ) ;
```

`%[^\n]` tells the `scanf` to read every character that is not `'\n'`. That leaves the `'\n'` character in the input buffer, then the `* (assignment suppression)` will consume the a single character `('\n')` but would not assign it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem is newline character `\n` leftover by the previous `scanf` after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This `\n` is left for the next call of `scanf`.
To avoid this problem you need to place a space before `%c` specifier in your `scanf`.

```
scanf(" %c", &C);  
...
scanf(" %c", &B);
...
scanf(" %c", &X);
```

A space before `%c` is able to eat up any number of newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using scanf to get the character ..and a new line will be added at the end of each input from user . So the second time only the new line will be stored in the 'B' Because of the first input given by you ..

Instead of scanf , change it to getchar - your problem should get solved

Comment: `getchar` too will come with extra `\n` in input when you press enter.

Comment: Using `getchar` instead of `scanf` will not solve this problem.