# Trouble with an Exponential

Tags: c, exponential

I cannot get the exponential to work with user input. Every time user is prompted to add input, after the input is entered the program immediately closes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   double input = 0;
   double exp_val;
   printf("Plese enter the exponent to check for convergence:");
   scanf("%f", input,"\n");
   printf("%f", input);/*Checking to verify the input is entered*/
   exp_val = exp(input);
   printf("%f", exp_val);
   getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @happydave's answer to use `&input`, you also need the `%lf` format specifier to read a double:

```
scanf("%lf", &input);
```

Check out [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

---

After this, you should get the correct answer, see it live: http://ideone.com/246clu.

Comment: Does the print statement need to remain %f, as it will immediatly close after the user enters their input

Comment: printf doesn't need %lf.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f

Comment: @user3259144 Check out the code (with running result) by the new link.

Comment: Thank you, although how do you keep the command prompt box in visual c from not immediately closing. Normally getchar() does this, but it seems to go around that and close anyways.

Comment: @user3259144 You can use `system("pause");` instead.

Answer (score 1):

scanf expects a pointer to the double, not the double itself:

```
scanf("%lf", &input);
```

This is because passing input directly passes by value.  But scanf doesn't want to know the current value of input, it wants to know the memory location where it should write the data that it reads.

Comment: I added the pointer, and it still crashed. Is there something I need to do to the double when it is initialized?

Comment: Try adding a second call to getchar.  Or read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653884/getchar-does-not-stop-when-using-scanf