# Press ENTER to continue (Linux & C)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, getchar

I am getting crazy here attempting to do something I thought it would be easy... :-)
Hopefully you guys can help me out.

This a C function written for a Linux Ubuntu...

All I need is to show a confirmation message and I expect the user to hit ENTER to continue.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>

    void setDeposit(int account, int amount)
    {
        printf("You have successfully transfered %d EUR to the account number %d\nPlease press ENTER to continue\n", account, amount);
        getchar();

    }
```

The application "ignores" the getchar() and simply moves on.

EDITED

Including the entire program as requested in the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "rbs-accmgr.c"
#include "rbs-graphics.c"
#include "rbs-struct.c"

//Main application function
int main()
{
    //Creating the application control instance
    application a = {1, 0, 0};

    //Populating the customer information with the login interface information
    customer c = {1234, "John", "Deer", 0};

    //Clearing the terminal window
    system("clear");

    //Keeps the application running as long as the user doesn't hit option 9 (Quit)
    while (a.status == 1)
    {
        //Displaying the graphic objects
        displayBanner();
        displayMenu();
        scanf("%d",&a.selectedOption);
        displayBanner();

        switch(a.selectedOption)
        {
            //Deposit
            case 1:
                printf("\nHow much would you like to deposit?\n");
                scanf("%d",&a.operationAmount);
                setDeposit(c.account, a.operationAmount);
                break;

            //Wrong option
            default:
                a.status = 0;
                break;
        }

        //Making sure all variables are zeroed
        a.operationAmount = 0;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: whats the error you are getting, or the problem you are facing??

Comment: Sorry guys. I have updated the question.

Comment: Works for me - there must be additional code which causes this. Are you reading additional input before (e.g. through `scanf()`)?

Comment: Show the `main()` function of your code where you call this `setDeposit()` function.

Comment: I would suggest you post the entire programm if its not to big, so that we can rebuild the error.

Comment: Entire program posted!

Comment: tl;dr : If you value your sanity avoid `scanf()` and `fscanf()`! They eat whitespace even crossing line boundaries. `sscanf()` can be useful, though.

Comment: And **_please_** don't use `#include` to inject other .c source files into your code. That's ugly and evil. Write your .c files so that the compiler can translate each of them independently. _Only_ `#include` proper .h header files which should only contain non-executable code, eg macro definitions, function prototypes and perhaps other types of declaration (there are exceptions to this rule but you don't need to worry about them at this stage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the one below and let me know. I think that `getChar` is used by that `scanf` you wrote. A `while` reading a separate `char` can rule that out. I wrote `\r` in case you use other operating systems.

```
void setDeposit(int account, int amount)
{
    printf("You have successfully transfered %d EUR to the account number %d\nPlease press ENTER to continue\n", account, amount);

    char myChar = 0;
    while (myChar != '\n' && myChar  != '\r') { 
        myChar = getchar(); 
    }
}
```

Detailed information about the case can be found within [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653884/getchar-does-not-stop-when-using-scanf).

Comment: Absolutely great. Thanks!

Comment: glad to know it worked.