# Cannot input from "gets()"

Tags: c

I wrote a c program that prompts the user enter their account information into the system and then print them out. I tried to use "gets()" to capture strings. However, it skipped the question for user's address and jumped into the question for state and city. I believed the problem is the "gets()"function. Could someone please help me with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 40
struct account
{
    long unsigned number;
    char address[MAXLEN];
    char cityState[MAXLEN];
    int zip;
    double balances;
    double credit;
    char name[MAXLEN];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct account memebr;
    puts("Please enter the account number");
    scanf("%lu", &memebr.number);
    puts("Please enter the street address");
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        gets(memebr.address);
    puts("Please enter your city/state");
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        gets(memebr.cityState);
    puts("Please enter your zip code");
    scanf("%d", &memebr.zip);
    puts("Please enter your balances");
    scanf("%lf", &memebr.balances);
    puts("Please enter your credit limit");
    scanf("%lf", &memebr.credit);
    puts("Please enter your name");
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        gets(memebr.name);

    printf("Account number: %lu\n", memebr.number);
    printf("The street address is : %s\n", memebr.address);
    printf("The owner comes from: %s\n", memebr.cityState);
    printf("The zip code is: %d\n", memebr.zip);
    printf("The owner's balances: %.2f\n", memebr.balances);
    printf("The owner's credit limit: %.2f\n", memebr.credit);
    printf("The owener is: %s\n", memebr.name);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What did you type in?

Comment: Why are you using `gets()`. It's no longer a standard function, and it's dangerous.

Comment: `while(getchar() != '\n') gets(memebr.address);` --> `while(getchar() != '\n'); gets(memebr.address);`, `while(getchar() != '\n') gets(memebr.cityState);` --> `gets(memebr.cityState);`, `while(getchar() != '\n') gets(memebr.name);` --> `while(getchar() != '\n'); gets(memebr.name);` Also `gets` has been abolished.

Comment: What do you think code like this does: `while(getchar() != '\n') gets(memebr.name);`?

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and in the latest c standard it is completely removed.  Your compiler should have told you that.   The best replacement is the function: `fgets()`  (which does have a different set of parameters from`gets()`   Suggest read the man page for `fgets()` so you will know what to expect and how to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for input twice, and `getchar()` will only return when the buffer is flushed, i.e when <kbd>Enter</kbd><sup>1</sup> is pressed. Thus, the `getchar()` call consumes everything and then you will have to type the same again for `gets()` to take it.

Try like this

```
fgets(member.name, sizeof(member.name), stdin);
```

instead of

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
    gets(member.name);
```

Notice that I replaced `gets()` with `fgets()` which is safer and is still part of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Actually, when `'\n'` is inserted into the buffer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the previous question "[getchar does not stop when using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653884/getchar-does-not-stop-when-using-scanf)", the input is only sent to the program after you typed a newline, but `scanf("%s", command );`leaves the newline in the input buffer. And then the following `getchar()` would return the newline immediately. That's why the program does not wait for the further input.

As a result, you need to make sure to clean your std input buffer before reading follow-up input. Modify your code:

```
scanf("%lu", &memebr.number);
puts("Please enter the street address");
while(getchar() != '\n')
    gets(memebr.address);
```

to

```
scanf("%lu", &memebr.number);                                                         
do {
  c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
puts("Please enter the street address");
gets(memebr.address);
```

should be ok to execute the program.